# to make a dropdown hide on click of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few `td` in my code.

The scenario is when I click on a `td`,the content below the `td` which is hidden on load needs to be displayed .

I have few events to handle with the elements in the dropdown.

I have used the same structure for all the `td`s, the problem is when I click on the first td, the dropdown appears and when I click on the second `td`, the dropdown elements coded in the second `td` also appears.

My scenario is when I click on any `td`, the dropdowns present below that `td` alone should appear and the other dropdown should disappear if they are shown.

My code is as follows:

```
$("#timeofday p").bind('click',function(event){
    $(this).parent().find(" > .dropdown").slideToggle();    
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'CLOSE' ? 'AFTERNOON' : 'CLOSE'); 
});
```

my html is as follows:

```
<tr>
<td  id="timeofday" class="avbltyltblue">
<p>AFTERNOON</p>
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="up" style="width:100px">UP</button></div>

<ul class="tlist">
<li>1:00PM</li>
<li>2:00PM</li>
<li>3:00PM</li>
<li>4:00PM</li>
<li>5:00PM</li>
<li>6:00PM</li>
<li>7:00PM</li>
<li>8:00PM</li>
<li>9:00PM</li>
<li>10:00PM</li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="down" style="width:100px">DOWN</button></div>
</div>
</td>
<td  id="timeofday" class="avbltyltblue">
<p>AFTERNOON</p>

<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="up" style="width:100px">UP</button></div>

<ul class="tlist">
<li>1:00PM</li>
<li>2:00PM</li>
<li>3:00PM</li>
<li>4:00PM</li>
<li>5:00PM</li>
<li>6:00PM</li>
<li>7:00PM</li>
<li>8:00PM</li>
<li>9:00PM</li>
<li>10:00PM</li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="down" style="width:100px">DOWN</button></div>
</div>
</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems to work:

```
$("#timeofday p").click(function(event){    


$("#timeofday .dropdown").slideUp();
$("#timeofday p").text($("#timeofday p").text('CLOSE') );

$(this).parent().find(" > .dropdown").slideToggle();    
$(this).text($(this).text('AFTERNOON') );
});
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/9LkDU/4/

Comment: my bad ! i forgot to add table in my html. the prob is say if i click on the first td, the dropdown appears and stays even if i click the second td. the scenario is if i click on the second td, the dropdown which is displayed bcoz of the click event on the first td should disappear. only the dropdown in the second td shud appear...

Comment: there still seems to be a small error which i am trying to fix.. when we click on the first td the dropdown opens up and when we click on the second td the dopdown closes which is as required. but if we click on the first td twice, it shud close. but it is not happening the slide is toggling again.. any ideas..?

Comment: Hi Zee Tee, thanks for the code. i added a if condition to it and this one http://jsfiddle.net/9LkDU/7/ seems to be working..:)

Answer (score 0):

onclick -- hide the element by making its `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` with JS..

```
var div  = document.getElementById("idOfYourElementToBeHidden");
div.style.visibility="hidden"; // this preserves the space occupied by the div
div.style.display="none"; // this frees up the space occupied by tat div
```